# sheaf inclusion of line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

Suppose $(X,\mathcal O _X)$ is a complex manifold, $L$ a line budle with nontrivial global section $s\in H^0(X,L)$. Then in sheaf category, one has a inclusion $\mathcal O_X\rightarrow L$. Notice that it is equivalent to for every open set $U\in X$, $\mathcal O_X(U)\rightarrow L(U)$ is injective. So does it mean that if $0\neq s\in H^0(X,L)$, $s_{|U}\neq 0$?

I know for holomorphic functions, there exist identity theorem. But in my opinion, there exists some differences between the two notions (take open covering...) So, how should I prove the sheaf inclusion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your actual question is: If $X$ is a connected complex manifold, $s$ is a holomorphic section of a holomorphic line bundle $L\to X$ and $s=0$ on a subset of $X$ with a limit point, must $s$ be identically $0$? Assume that $L$ is trivial over an open set containing that limit point. Now what?

Comment: @TedShifrin, the zero set is a divisor, so if s vanish on an open set, it must vanish identically?

Comment: Well, I was looking for a self-contained argument of a stronger statement. But if you want to claim this, why are you posting the question?

Comment: @Ted Sorry, I still can't figure out how to answer your first question...

Comment: The question reduces immediately to the standard identity principle from complex analysis.  Having that, you just glue on overlaps of trivializations.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I get it. So now, $X=\left\{U_i\right\}$, if $s_{|U_i}=0$, by $s_i=g_{ij}s_j$, it follows that $s_j$ vanish on $U_{ij}$, then $s_j$ vanish on $U_j$, at last, $s=0$ as a contraction. Am I right?

Comment: Right. I was stating a stronger version, but this is all you need.

Comment: @Ted, yes, sorry for my first comment and really appreciate your help.